# PHP Switch multiple parameters

Tags: php, syntax, switch-statement

is there a way of making this look more organized?

```
if (!isset( $par2 ) && !isset( $par3 )) {
        $where = "lvlOne = '".$par1."'";

    } elseif(isset( $par2 ) && !isset( $par3 )) {
        $where = "lvlOne = '".$par1."' AND lvlTwo = '".$par2."'";

    } elseif(isset( $par2 ) && isset( $par3 )) {
        $where = "lvlOne = '".$par1."' AND lvlTwo = '".$par2."' AND lvlThree = '".$par3."'";
    }
```

Comment: You can pass multiple parameters to isset()

Comment: Looks like you're constructing a query. Why not prepare this?

Comment: sure. some plastic bins, coat of paint, bit of dusting, we'll have it looking like new in no time.

Comment: @Dave Chen what do you mean with prepare this? I'm constructing a query.

Comment: @FacuFerrari: He meant to use "prepared statements" http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about formatting their code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenation:

```
$where = "lvlOne = '{$par1}'";

if(isset( $par2 )) {
    $where .= " AND lvlTwo = '{$par2}'";
}

if(isset( $par3 )) {
    $where .= " AND lvlThree = '{$par3}'";
}
```

Concatenation with ternary:

```
$where = "lvlOne = '{$par1}'";
$where .= isset($par2)?" AND lvlTwo = '{$par2}'":'';
$where .= isset($par3)?" AND lvlThree = '{$par3}'":'';
```

Implode with array:

```
//where this one is nice is that regardless of the number of parameters,
//you always end up with the proper 'AND' between each where clause.
$where = array("lvlOne = '{$par1}'");
if(isset($par2)){
    $where[] = "lvlTwo = '{$par2}'"
}
if(isset($par3)){
    $where[] = "lvlThree = '{$par3}'"
}
$where = impode(' AND ', $where);
```

In the end though, if it works and isn't some holy abomination, daily wtf worthy code, why worry about what it looks like? It does follow a simple syntax structure (ie indented).

Edit: Changed to just enclosing variable with curly braces because we are already inside of double quotes.

Comment: Nice!, I'd like to see more options but I like this one.

Comment: Just to learn!, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
 $where = "lvlOne = '{$par1}'";
if (isset( $par2 )) { $where .= " AND lvlTwo = '{$par2}'"; } 
if(isset( $par3 )) { $where .= "AND lvlTwo = '{$par2}' AND lvlThree = '{$par3}'";  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this would be quite a bit cleaner.

```
$where = "lvlOne = '".$par1."'";
if(isset($par2)) {$where .= " AND lvlTwo = '".$par2."'";}
if(isset($par3)) {$where .= " AND lvlThree = '".$par3."'";}
```